# Why Django does not create full table from a model?

Tags: database, django, django-models, syncdb, manage.py

I have 2 models. I run manage.py syncdb but it creates only id fields for 2 models. How to make it generate the remaining fields? Please kindly advise. Your help is much appreciated!

Here's my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

GENDER_CHOICES = (
    ('M', 'Male')
    , ('F', 'Female')
)

ACTIVATION_CHOICES = (
    ('Y', 'Activate')
    , ('N', 'Inactive')
)

FULL_PART_CHOICES = (
    ('F', 'Full-time')
    , ('P', 'Part-time')
)

# Create your models here.
class Teachers(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False),
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False),
    mname = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False),
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False),
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=False),
    nric = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True, null=False),
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, unique=True, null=False),
    dob = models.DateField(null=False),
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False),
    block = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False),
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False),
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False),
    handphone = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True, null=False),
    homephone = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=False),
    activated = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACTIVATION_CHOICES, null=False),
    date_ttc = models.DateField(null=False),
    full_part = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=FULL_PART_CHOICES, null=False),
    nonce = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, null=False),
    passwd = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False),
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False),
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=False),

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Teacher %s %s %s" % (self.fname, self.mname, self.lname)

# Create your models here.
class Admins(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, null=False),
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False),
    mname = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False),
    lname = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False),
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=False),
    nric = models.CharField(max_length=12, unique=True, null=False),
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, unique=True, null=False),
    dob = models.DateField(null=False),
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False),
    block = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False),
    street = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False),
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False),
    handphone = models.CharField(max_length=16, unique=True, null=False),
    homephone = models.CharField(max_length=16, null=False),
    activated = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACTIVATION_CHOICES, null=False),
    nonce = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, null=False),
    passwd = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False),
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=False),
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=False),

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "Admin %s %s %s" % (self.fname, self.mname, self.lname)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was too easy. There were lots of redundant commas after each field declaration. I removed those and everything worked fine.

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

You can either drop the tables if you don't have any data on them or use `django-south` which you can use for migrating.